# Disable abrtd for executables stored in project directory

Tags: abrt

I have the following problem with the `abrt` daemon:

For a tuning application I am executing the same program over and over again. A lot of the times the program I am executing fails. That is no problem and actually expected, but after thousands of fails `abrtd` runs at 100% CPU usage.

Because I don't need the error reporting from `abrt` I would like to configure it to ignore all crashes that happen from executables stored in my project directory. I found the `BlackListedPaths` configuration keyword, but I can not access the configuration file under /etc because I do not have admin privileges.

Is there a way to to configure `abrtd` as described above without admin rights?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to disable the `abrt` error reporting without admin rights by creating a file under `~/.config/abrt/abrt.conf` with `BlackListedPaths = /path/to/project/` as its content.